# How can I scrape text from tooltip using selenium? Page does not contain tooltip html

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape items from page using selenium. Currently I am stuck at scraping text from item tooltip.

[image: item with the tooltip]

Html that I see using developer tools (f12) for one item in a page:

```
<div class="offer-page-sale-item offer-page-sale-item__actual" data-real-id="12345" data-id="12345-4">
    <!-- Render product -->
    <div class="item ">
        <div class="discount price bare">
            <div class="t1">
                <span class="value">1</span>
                <span class="cents">69</span>
                <span class="eur">€</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tags tags_primary">
            <div class="tag i tooltipstered"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="img"></div>

        <div class="text">
            <div class="title">[name of the product]</div>
            <div class="pack">
                <span class="ptitle"></span>
                <span class="price"> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infopop">
            <div class="in"><span></span>
                <div class="arrow_top"></div>
                <div class="arrow_bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</div>
```

If I look into html from page source (ctrl+u) for the same item I see:

```
<div class="offer-page-sale-item offer-page-sale-item__actual" data-real-id="12345" data-id="12345-4">
    <!-- Render product -->
    <div class="item ">
        <div class="discount price bare">
            <div class="t1">
                <span class="value">1</span>
                <span class="cents">69</span>
                <span class="eur">€</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tags tags_primary">
            <div title="[product price valid from]-[product price valid until]" class="tag i"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="img"></div>

        <div class="text">
            <div class="title">[name of the product]</div>
            <div class="pack">
                <span class="ptitle"></span>
                <span class="price"> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infopop">
            <div class="in"><span></span>
                <div class="arrow_top"></div>
                <div class="arrow_bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</div>
```

So the only difference is inside `<div class="tags tags_primary">` tag.
Because I can actually can see the text when using page source, I imagine I should be able to capture it?
However, Selenium driver gives me only `class="tag i tooltipstered"` tag, and not `class="tag i"` which has `title` attribute I need.

I have tried to:

1. use `Actions class MoveToElement()` but still could not find tooltip title.
2. use `IJavaScriptExecutor` to get `innerHtml` of `<div class="tags tags_primary">` without luck.

If someone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPD:**
Rewrited @PDHide phyton code to c#.
Created extension for IWebDriver:

```
public static IWebElement WaitUntilVisible(this IWebDriver driver, By itemSpecifier, int secondsTimeout = 10)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsTimeout));
    var element = wait.Until<IWebElement>(driver =>
    {
        try
        {
            var elementToBeDisplayed = driver.FindElement(itemSpecifier);
            if (elementToBeDisplayed.Displayed)
            {
                return elementToBeDisplayed;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    });
    return element;
}
```

Then used it to collect text from tooltip:

```
using(IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.maxima.lt/akcijos");
    _driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.CssSelector("#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowallSelectionWrapper #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll")).Click();
    _driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.ClassName("close")).Click();
    var tool = _driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.CssSelector("[class='tag i tooltipstered']"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(_driver);
    actions.MoveToElement(tool).Build().Perform();
    var tooltip = _driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.ClassName("tooltipster-content"));
    Console.WriteLine(tooltip.Text);
}
```

Comment: You can see my example live at maxima.lt/akcijos

Comment: Do you have link to that website

Comment: @PDHide see my previous comment. Link to website is [this](https://maxima.lt/akcijos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver




driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.maxima.lt/akcijos")

#close cookies 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowallSelectionWrapper #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll'))
).click()


#close ad pop up
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'close'))
).click()

#find information icon
tool = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="tag i tooltipstered"]'))
)


driver.maximize_window()

#move to information icon
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(tool).perform()

#find the tool tip
tooltip = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'tooltipster-content'))
)

#print the content
print(tooltip.text)
```

This is the python code you can use the same logic sequence for c#